# Is there a way to prevent/disable click event from occurring on event.target?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

I am working on a Tic Tac Toe game and decided to use an event bubbling concept in the project, so that every time a user clicks on 1 of the 9 fields inside a container (`event.currentTarget`), a certain figure (X or O) is inserted in one of the selected fields (in this case a span tag). However after the figure is inserted I would like to prevent/disable event listener from occurring again on the field which was already clicked. The event listener is set on the parent element, which in my case is the container for all 9 fields. Below you can find some sample code:

```js
function insertFigure (e) {
    if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
        
        if (game.currentPlayer === "O") {
            if (!event.target.childNodes[0].classList.contains("fa", "fa-circle-o") || !event.target.childNodes[0].classList.contains("fa", "fa-times")) {
                event.target.childNodes[0].classList.add("fa", "fa-circle-o");
                
            } else {
                alert ("There is already a figure");
            }
        } else if (game.currentPlayer === "X") {
            if (!event.target.childNodes[0].classList.contains("fa", "fa-times") || !event.target.childNodes[0].classList.contains("fa", "fa-circle-o")) {
                event.target.childNodes[0].classList.add("fa", "fa-times");

            } else {
                alert ("There is already a figure");
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    e.stopPropagation()
}
```

```html
      <div id="container-board">
             <div id="cell-1" class="cell bottom-right-border"><span></span></div>
             <div id="cell-2" class="cell bottom-right-border"><span></span></div>
             <div id="cell-3" class="cell bottom-border"><span></span></div>
             <div id="cell-4" class="cell bottom-right-border"><span></span></div>
             <div id="cell-5" class="cell bottom-right-border"><span></span></div>
             <div id="cell-6" class="cell bottom-border"><span></span></div>
             <div id="cell-7" class="cell right-border"><span></span></div>
             <div id="cell-8" class="cell right-border"><span></span></div>
             <div id="cell-9" class="cell"><span></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you tell what game refers to in your insertFigure function?

Comment: Sorry i've fogotten to include it in my post:

 let game = {
        user: '',
        computer: '',
        currentPlayer: 'O',
        moves: 1,
        boxes: ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
        score: {
            playerX: 0,
            playerO: 0
        },
        turn: ''
    };

Comment: Just test for `if (!event.target.childNodes[0].classList.contains("fa"))`, as that is the class that all elements that had already been clicked on will have